# Macro to copy from Excel to Netsuite Fields

Tags: excel, netsuite

Im trying to create a macro to copy parcel tracking numbers from excel 2010 and paste directly into Netsuite but cannot find the correct place to start. Anyone able to help?

Data is stored in columns with the Sales ref as the data header and the tracking number as column 2 (Generated by current online carrier software)

Integrated software will be sourced but im trying to create a 'for now' workaround

Thanks

Comment: Is there any issue using the CSV import tool?

Comment: I want the data extracted to excel in a specific column layout to save operational time so not sure if the CSV tool is that flexible